# How to remove span tag using jquery without using remove method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

can you please tell me how to remove the span tag using jquery.
**INPUT**

```
<span class="abc">PQR </span>
```

**OUTPUT**

```
PQR
```

I done before but don't remember I think I used regex or replace .:(

Second

How to replace &nbsp by a space(" ") ?

I used like that but not work.

```
replace(/&nbsp;/g,'');
```

Comment: Why do you need to remove without using remove()? Just access the span with .text() and then remove using remove().

Comment: I want to search a text .that why ? actually i am getting data from server having &nbsp

Answer (score 3):

For the first part, Tim's answer is great. `$('.abd').contents().unwrap()`.

For the second part, *please* do it properly. `&nbsp;` is an html-encoded special characters (non-breakable space), but there are tons of other characters you can encounter (like `&eacute;` for `é`).

Unfortunately there's no built-in standard html decode function, but you can create one with jquery like this:

```
function htmlDecode(encodedText) {
  return $("<div>").html(encodedText).text();
}
```

Comment: not sure about that. Your fiddle is convoluted and I'm not certain to get what your problem actually is. Maybe try to simplify your fiddle to its core elements and post another question?

Answer (score 2):

For the first part, you can use `$('.abc').contents().unwrap()`

For the second part see jods answer :)

Comment: can you use this on my searching example .First you remove all this than search

Comment: on search button click you just remove &nbsp and span tag then search http://jsfiddle.net/AzRcn/7/

Comment: on search button click